# Changing my Game Center ID

Tags: sharing, apple-id, game-center

If I am sharing an Apple ID with my son, can I change my Game Center name without messing up his games on his iPod?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you mean changing your nickname. If so, you must go into the ME section of GameCenter, tap `Account` (where it says your email), hit `View Account`, then `Edit Account Info`. Scroll down to `Nickname` to change your name. However, I believe that the names may still be linked to the Apple ID and will therefore appear on your son's iPod. If that is the case, he may have to follow the above steps as well.